# Avoid object being added to the cache

Tags: cachingframework.redis

In the example

```
var user = context.Cache.FetchObject<User>(redisKey, () => 
GetUserNameFromDatabase(id));


string GetUserNameFromDatabase(string userid) 
{
   return string.empty();
}
```

how do I prevent the string.empty result to be added to the cache.... causing it to call the function again next timeGetUserNameFromDatabase

Would be nice with some kind of check delegate, that if returns true will cause the result to be added and otherwise not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's needed since you can actually prevent results to being added to the cache by just returning NULL. When the invoked delegate returns NULL, no value will be added to the redis cache. Check [RedisCacheProvider.cs](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis/blob/master/src/CachingFramework.Redis/Providers/RedisCacheProvider.cs#L334) code.

So you can do the validations in your delegate:

```
var user = context.Cache.FetchObject<User>(redisKey, () => GetUserNameFromDatabase(id));

string GetUserNameFromDatabase(string userid) 
{
   return (GetUserFromDb(userid) == String.Empty) ? null : user;
}
```